# angularJs / mobileAngular: how to increase font size at higher res?

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile

I created a simple app where user enter a product code and output the actual number of pieces in our warehouse.

All is working, but a user have a phone with 720p display and all is working, ok, but text is really TOO SMALL.

How can I increase text size for higher res displays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the head of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Actually I've this: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

Comment: Ok... `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` stops Android from performing scaling in your web page, so probably shouldn't use that.  Did you try replacing your tag with the one I gave you?